# How do I do I know when my mac app enters background?

Tags: cocoa

I'd like to do some things in my mac app when a user starts using another app or the Finder and my app isn't in focus anymore.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe the `NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification` to find out when you aren't the active application anymore.  This and related notifications are documented in the [*NSApplication Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000012-BAJFCBDJ).

If you don't know how to observe notifications, you will want to read [*Notification Programming Topics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).